# How to properly use whileloop to return afterwhileloop value

Tags: ocaml

The goal is to write a parse tree generator that takes as input an arithmetic expression of type string and output a parse tree. In the provided codes below,  we can see three mutually recursive methods expr(), term(), primary().  expr() has to return a parse tree by going through the input arithmetic expression string.  The parse rules are defined by Exp -> Term|{+Term}, Term -> Primary*Primary,  Primary -> a|b|c...|z|(Exp). The codes can generate the correct parse tree if there is only one + used. For example, with an input string like "a+b", the codes produce Exp( '+', Var a, Var b ). The code fails in expression with more than one +.  For example, a+b+c gives Exp('+', Var a, Var b) but it should really be Exp('+', Var a, Exp('+', Var b ,Var c).

```
exception NotImplemented
type exptree = Var of char | Expr of char * exptree * exptree
let charSet =['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'g'; 'h'; 'i'; 'j'; 'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n'; 'o';
   'p'; 'q'; 'r'; 's'; 't'; 'u'; 'v'; 'w'; 'x'; 'y'; 'z'] 

let rec isin charr charlist =
match charlist with
| []-> false
|q::w -> if q=charr then true else isin charr w 

let parse (inputexp: string): exptree =
  let sym = ref inputexp.[0] in
  let cursor = ref 0 in

  let getsym () =
    cursor := !cursor + 1;
    sym := inputexp.[!cursor]
  in

  let rec expr (): exptree =
    let p = term() in
    match !sym with
    | '+' -> (getsym(); Expr ('+',p,term()))
    | _ -> p

  and term (): exptree =
    let p = primary() in
    match !sym with
    | '*' -> getsym() ;Expr ('*',p,primary())
    | _ -> p

  and primary (): exptree =
    if !sym = '('
    then begin
      getsym ();
      let result = expr () in
      if !sym <> ')' then
        failwith "Mismatched parens"
      else if !cursor = (String.length inputexp) - 1  then
        result
      else begin
        getsym ();
        result
      end
    end
    else
    if isin !sym charSet then
      if !cursor = (String.length inputexp) - 1 then
        Var !sym
      else
        let result = Var !sym in
        begin
          getsym ();
          result
        end
    else
      failwith "In primary"
  in
  expr ()
```

So this shows that we have a problem that expr does not go beyond the first + in the input string.  While using a while loop seem promising. However, the recursive call returns a parse tree after it sees the first + rather than looking for the next one.  Hence please help this one solve this problem.

Comment: You might want to reduce this to a [mcve]. Not very many people will want spend much effort on what seems like little more than code and assignment dump. But if you put some effort into helping the people who want to help you. you're much more likely to receive an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the codes now you can copy and past to try it out. you can do for example    parse "a+b" to get Expr('+',Var a,Var b). so if you do parse "a+b+c" it wouldn't work. Thank you for being considerate haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a value from the `while` loop you can use an exception. Here is the example, which uses a `while true` loop and escapes from it using an exception that uses the return as a payload

```
exception Finished of int

let compute m =
  let n = ref 0 in
  let r = ref 1 in
  try
    while true do
      if !n < m
      then begin
        r := !r + !r;
        incr n;
      end
      else
        raise_notrace (Finished !r)
    done;
    assert false
  with Finished x -> x;;
```

Note, that we have to add the `assert false` statement to tell the compiler that this line of code is unreachable. If your loop is not a `while true` loop and can terminate either normally or exceptionally, then it will loop like this:

```
let compute m =
  let n = ref 0 in
  let r = ref 1 in
  try
    while !n < m do
      incr n;
      r := !r + !r;
      if !r > 4096 then raise_notrace (Finished !r)
    done;
    !r
  with Finished x -> x;;
```

Note, this is, of course, a non-idiomatic code for OCaml, we prefer to use recursion to implement recursive algorithms. Also, unlike other languages, OCaml provides very cheap exceptions, so calling an exception is as cheap as using `goto` in C. We used the `raise_notrace` operator to raise an exception without recording the backtrace, to ensure this.